# Redirect boost log message to Window control

Tags: boost

I am making MFC windows application with boost library.
I want to redirect boost log messages into Windows control like ListBox to see it on GUI window.

I think I need to implement the a sink backend which eventually posts a log message to destination windows using `PostMessage()` API.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is self-answer.
I should take a look library source files that relate with log facility.
Thanks boost. It isn't difficult to make custom log sink.
I referenced debug_output_backend.hpp file in boost library.

```cpp
#include <boost/log/core.hpp>
#include <boost/log/utility/setup/common_attributes.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sinks/sync_frontend.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sinks/basic_sink_backend.hpp>
#include <boost/log/trivial.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>

namespace logging = boost::log;
namespace sinks = boost::log::sinks;
class customlog_sink : public sinks::basic_formatted_sink_backend<char, sinks::concurrent_feeding>
{
public:
    void consume(const logging::record_view& rec, const string_type& fstring)
    {
        std::ostringstream os;
        os << "<" << rec[boost::log::trivial::severity] << "> " << fstring;
        ::PostMessage(hwnd_, UWM_LOG_MESSAGE, 0, (LPARAM)strdup(os.str().c_str()));
    }

    customlog_sink(HWND hwnd)
        : hwnd_(hwnd)
    {
    }

private:
    HWND hwnd_;
};

void init_log(HWND hwnd)
{
   typedef sinks::synchronous_sink< customlog_sink > sink_t;


   boost::shared_ptr< sink_t > sink(new sink_t(hwnd));
   boost::shared_ptr< logging::core > core = logging::core::get();

   core->add_sink(sink);
}
```